# Writing values to a float4x4 matrix in iOS Metal - existing float values replaced

Tags: swift, matrix, metal, particles

I am trying to make a buffer to count particles / points in certain cells of an evenly spaced grid (each particle would be added to a cell based on its position). The index of each particle would then be stored in a float4x4 matrix corresponding to each cell, for lookup later. I am using an atomic counter to add a particle count for each cell, so that the number of particles does not exceed 16, and using this counter to sequentially add the particle indices to the matrix.

When the number of rows or number of columns is > 4, i.e. next column / row, the index in the position[0] is written to 0.0. I am not sure if this is something to do with the way the columns are overwritten in a float4x4 matrix, or if there is something to do with the way the memory is allocated / pointer for the float4x4. Basically, I just want to add and change individual values sequentially, without it affecting the existing values in the matrix.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks so much!

Here is the kernel:

```
kernel void findCellandCount(  device Particle *particles [[ buffer(0) ]],
                     volatile device atomic_uint *cellCountArray [[buffer(1)]],
                     device float4x4* cellIndicesBuffer [[ buffer(2) ]],
                     uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
  
    uint particleIndex = id;
    
    Particle particle = particles[particleIndex];

    const float cellSize = Params().cellWidth;

*// GET CELL INDEX:*

    int2 cellIndex = int2(fast::floor(particle.position.x / cellSize), fast::floor(particle.position.y / cellSize)); 

    uint flatCellIndex = GetFlatCellIndex(cellIndex, numberGridCells); // this is in the range 0-15 (16 cells)
    
    // This is a counter to store particle count in each cell // this is reset to zero each frame:
    int cellCounter = atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&cellCountArray[flatCellIndex], 1, memory_order_relaxed);
        
    if (cellCounter < 16) { // i.e. count is less than 4x4 float matrix 

        uint a = cellCounter % 4;
        uint b = cellCounter / 4;

    //m[index][column][row]

        cellIndicesBuffer[flatCellIndex][a][b] = id; // this writes the particle index to the float4x4
 
    }
  
}
```

This is the output from the cells:

```
Cell:  3 cell indices:  simd_float4x4([[23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [61.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
```

^ this output is as expected, with 4 indices stored in the first 4 rows

```
Cell:  8 cell indices:  simd_float4x4([[0.0, 38.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 39.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 42.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 63.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
```

^ here there are 8 indices stored, but the value at position[0] is overwritten / replaced by 0.0.

```
Cell:  9 cell indices:  simd_float4x4([[0.0, 35.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 45.0, 0.0, 0.0], [13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [28.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
```

^ here there are 6 indices stored, but again the values at the first position are overwritten.

Comment: Where have you defined `cellIndex` that you use in the call to `GetFlatCellIndex`?  It's not in the parameter list, nor defined as a local variable.

Comment: Hi Chip, I have added the cell index code; the getFlatCellIndex function just returns a hashed value bashed on the position: `int n = p1 * cellIndex.x ^ p2*cellIndex.y; n %= partitionBucketCount;` where p1 and p2 are large primes

Comment: I could be wrong, but I *think* you may have your `a` and `b` matrix index computations backwards.  It's been a while since I've needed to use the SIMD matrix types, but as I recall they are column major, which means not only is the column index specified first when using the subscript operator, but that the memory layout is all of the elements of a column are consecutive followed by all of the elements of the next column, etc...  So if consecutive `cellCounter` values address down each column before moving to the next, `a` should be `cellCounter / 4` and `b` should be `cellCounter % 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I know what's going on.  In your code where you have

```cpp
cellIndicesBuffer[flatCellIndex][a][b] = id;
```

I think the effect of that line is essentially this:

```cpp
float4x4 temp = cellIndicesBuffer[flatCellIndex];
temp[a][b] = id;
cellIndicesBuffer[flatCellIndex] = temp;
```

Although you are using `atomic_uint` to guard against data races on elements of your `cellCountArray` array, you aren't guarding against it with your `cellIndicesBuffer` elements, and doing so would be problematic for performance anyway.

The problem, I think, stems from `float4x4` being a SIMD type - essentially a `struct`.  I'm suggesting that it reads the whole thing into gpu-thread local memory (probably registers), updates the element, then writes the whole thing back out to the array, overwriting elements of the `float4x4` that may have been written by other threads in the intervening time.  To avoid that, you'd need to address only the element you want to update without going through the `float4x4`, which you can do by recasting the `cellIndicesBuffer` as a `float*`.

```cpp
auto i = flatCellIndex * 16 + a * 4 + b;
reinterpret_cast<device float*>(cellIndicesBuffer)[i] = id;
```

If you intend for consecutive `cellCounter` values to fill down each column before proceeding to the next column, you could eliminate `a` and `b`:

```cpp
auto i = flatCellIndex * 16 + cellCounter;
reinterpret_cast<device float*>(cellIndicesBuffer)[i] = id;
```

I should mention that responsible C++ programmers are probably, rightly, cringing at my use of `reinterpret_cast` here.  If you don't need to use `cellIndicesBuffer` specifically as `device float4x4*` anywhere else in the shader function, which you don't in your code as provided, it would be better to just change the parameter type to `device float*`. Then you don't have to do the `reinterpret_cast`.  You shouldn't need any changes in your Swift code.